# pg jdbc dns failover

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

According to [pgjdbc documantation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connection-fail-over), the driver supports failover when ip addresses and ports of host are comma separated, like this:
`jdbc:postgresql://my-db-host-slave-1:5432,my-db-host-master-1:5432/database?targetServerType=primary`.

Bot it's not convenient, because we use k8s for pg, and there may be more slaves added and master ip may be changed.

I want to store all my hosts in DNS and to specify one hostname like this:
`jdbc:postgresql://my-db-host.local:5432/database?targetServerType=primary`

I have a dns record with 2 ip addresses:

```
$ nslookup my-db-host.local
Server: 192.168.1.1 
Address: 192.168.1.1#53 

Non-authoritative answer:  
Name: my-db-host-slave-1
Address: 192.168.10.21 
Name: my-db-host-master-1
Address: 192.168.11.25
```

and I tried to specify it like this:
`jdbc:postgresql://my-db-host.local:5432/database?targetServerType=primary`.
But this way it only picks the first ip - slave and fails with `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not find a server with specified targetServerType: primary`

Is there any workaround for using dns failover? May be some options in connection pools if driver does not support that?